# Packer,Jenkins, Cloudformation, how to make them work together?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, aws-cloudformation, packer

First of all my apologies that the question is under stackoverflow not stack exchange, I don't have enough points to ask it there.

I've created a packer template in which creates my image(the image includes the code for my application, nginx, php-fpm and ...)
If you have used packer before, you will know that at the end of the process it will give you the image_id, I need to use this image id in order to update the template for my cloudformation on aws, 
the cloud formation template will create an launch configuration based on the image_id from the packer.  later on the launch configuration will be used to create an autoscaling group,which is  connected to an ELB(The ELB is not under cloudformation).

Here are my questions:

1-whats the best way to automate the process of getting the id from packer and updating the cloudformation template?(To elaborate more, i need to get the id somehow, for now the only thing that I can think of is a bash command, but this cause an issue if I want to use jenkins later on.what are other alternatives?)

2-Lets say I managed to get the id, now whats the best policy to update the cloudformation template?(Currently aws CLI is my only option any better solution)?

2-How to automate these whole process using jenkins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would put a wrapper Python/Ruby script that would run packer, then call cloudformation reading from the packer output.

Comment: The question is for long back, so I ended up doing the exact same thing.Thanks for your respond though.